# Import inline SVG from absolute path on Next.JS

Tags: typescript, svg, babeljs, next.js, eslint

I am having difficulties in configuring Next.Js to make imports in absolute way.

I configured **tsconfig.json** using **baseUrl** as **"src"** and it even works, except for inline SVG files. I'm using the **'inline-react-svg'** that works if you import relative path but completely ignores the absolute path that I configured. And regardless of whether the import is working or not, **Eslint** is giving an error. Here is the code:

First, my structure looks like this:

> - src
>
>   - assets
>   - pages
>   - styles

#### tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
  ]
}
```

#### babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": [
    ["styled-components", { "ssr": true }],
    "inline-react-svg"
  ]
}
```

#### .eslintrc.json

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true,
    "node": true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "standard",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "prettier/@typescript-eslint",
    "prettier/standard",
    "prettier/react"
  ],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": 12,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": [
    "react",
    "@typescript-eslint",
    "prettier"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": "error",
    "space-before-function-paren": "off",
    "react/prop-types": "off",
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off"

  }
}
```

### Examples:

In the file **"./src/pages/_app.tsx"** it imports the theme (**theme.ts**) and **GlobalStyles** of the Styled Components absolutely as expected:

#### src/pages/_app.tsx

```
import GlobalStyle from 'styles/global'
import theme from 'styles/theme'
```

Check that it didn't need to return the folders with **'../'**, but in **index.tsx** it imports the SVG only relatively.

#### src/pages/index.tsx

```
import Logo from '../assets/logo.svg' /* assim funciona */
import Logo from 'assets/logo.svg' /* assim não funciona */
```

Yet another! Whatever if it works or not, the Eslint pisses you with an error message saying that file don't exists or the types is not defined.

> Cannot find module '../assets/logo.svg' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

Well, I'm using **Next.JS 10.0.5** with **'next-images'**. I think it adds the typing to all image files, including **SVG**. Am I right? What configuration do I have to make for this error to occur and to be able to import the SVG inline absolutely?